# Does "somewhere and sometime" make sense, alluding to the future?

Tags: word-choice

If referring to an issue that can´t be resolved here and now in a song (a break up) and if hoping that this matter could at least be discussed under better circumstances in the future. Would the phrase "But somewhere and sometime" make any sense? Could it be the title of the song?

Comment: "Someday" is more common in this sort of context than "some time", but "sometime" is not unknown; for instance, Rosanne Cash's [Somewhere Sometime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvjQVxvV3Xs&index=5&list=PLVMevu8LMo7eakpZMbJ2V9572zTZ7jf1C) matches your question pretty precisely.

Comment: @StoneyB, that sounds like a pretty darn good answer. Why not drop the other proverbial shoe and make it one?

Answer (score 1):

*Someday*, which is used almost exclusively for events in the indefinite future, is probably more common in this sort of context than *sometime*, which may be used for both past and future events; it has a 'yearning' sense almost built in. Stephen Sondheim's lyric to "Somewhere", from Bernstein's *West Side Story*, is instructive.

> There's a place for us,
> Somewhere a place for us.
> Peace and quiet and open air
> Wait for us
> Somewhere.
>
> There's a time for us,
> Some day a time for us,
> Time together with time to spare,
> Time to learn, time to care,
> Some day!

Despite *time* in the first four lines of the second verse, Sondheim lands on *day* for his big cadence.

It's probably not irrelevant that *-ay* is more singable than *-ime*, or that it's a lot easier to find rhymes in *-ay* than in *-ime*.

But *sometime* is certainly not unknown. At least eight different songs are to be found on YouTube titled "Somewhere Sometime" or "Sometime Somewhere" or something very similar. Rosanne Cash's "Somewhere Sometime" matches your idea almost exactly:

"Somewhere Sometime"

> I was a wise insider – I knew the score
> I kept him on those heartstrings, begging for more
> No chance for real emotion here, no end in sight
> I watched him slip away from me, night after night
>
> I came so close to breaking down, didn’t turn away
> I don’t want to reveal that much, baby; I don’t want to pay
> Don’t want the keys to paradise, nobody’s home
> Don’t want to feel the fire and ice sleeping alone
>
> Somewhere … Sometime
> Some way … he’ll change his mind
>
> Maybe he’s lost in the confusion
> Maybe he wants somebody new, but I ain’t through with him
> And I don’t want to lose him out there
>
> Somewhere … Sometime
> Some way … he’ll change his mind

You can hear the song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvjQVxvV3Xs&index=5&list=PLVMevu8LMo7eakpZMbJ2V9572zTZ7jf1C).